# How can I make a self-join on a large table more efficient?

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I am currently trying to find potential duplicate customers created within the last 6 months that match all historic customers in a relatively large (760,000+ rows) table. In my situation, what classifies 2 customers as similar is a [DIFFERENCE](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/difference-transact-sql?view=sql-server-2017) value of 4 on the first and last names, different customer IDs, and a similar DOB (either customer 1 DOB = customer 2 DOB, or customer 1 DOB is null, or customer 2 DOB is null). I am currently trying to achieve this by self-joining the table like so:

```
SELECT *
FROM    (SELECT * FROM Customer c WHERE c.Created >= DATEADD(MONTH, -6, GETUTCDATE())) c1
JOIN    (SELECT * FROM Customer) c2 ON c1.CustomerID <> c2.CustomerID
WHERE   (c1.DOB IS NULL OR c2.DOB IS NULL OR c1.DOB = c2.DOB)
        AND DIFFERENCE(c1.FirstName, c2.FirstName) = 4
        AND DIFFERENCE(c1.LastName, c2.LastName) = 4
```

When I remove the DOB condition, the query works well enough (around 2 or 3 seconds to execute); however, as soon as I add that condition back in, the query just keeps spinning until my machine runs out of memory. The query also works well (albeit a bit slowly) when the DOB null checks are not included  (i.e. just the `c1.DOB = c2.DOB` piece). Any advice on how I can refactor/optimize this query would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: Please provide sample data and desired results, along with a clear description of what you are doing.

Comment: What indexes are on the table? How does the execution plan look like?

Comment: Please see [paste the plan](https://www.brentozar.com/pastetheplan/instructions/) for a way to include an execution plan in your question.

Comment: You can use temp tables. For e.g. in your case the "FROM" part of the query can be loaded into temp table and indexes can be created on CustomerID, FirstName, LastName and DOB. This way your in your "JOIN" for C2 you won't need "select *". I would recommend to avoid inequality on joins. In your case, I am unable to see a single column that can be used for join so it may be difficult. Hope this helps.

Comment: @skadam85 An index on `DoB` might be used intelligently by the query optimizer, but `FirstName` and `LastName` have to go through `Difference()` and `CustomerId` is just a mismatch so indexing isn't likely to help. (The OP's description implies that the `DoB` processing isn't as clever as one might hope.) `Include` the other columns with an index on `DoB` may provide some improvement in physical reads. It makes me curious as to whether `union all` of a `c1.DoB is NULL or c2.DoB is NULL` and `c1.DoB = c2.Dob` queries might improve performance.

Comment: Try adding an index on the DoB column. If it already exists, try removing it!

Comment: I solved my issue using temporary tables for each different DOB condition (3 temp tables total) and `union`-ing them together as recommended by skadam85 and HABO. Thank you for the advice!